# Firefox profile export/backup tool

Tags: gratis, backup, firefox, utility

I want to be able to backup, or export, my Firefox profile, then later be able to apply this backup - import into an existing (new) profile, or import/restore as a separate profile. I do *not* want to back up absolutely everything, e.g. no caches, no arbitrary files which might have been saved into the profile folder by mistake and so on.

I need to do this on Linux. I don't  mind if it's a GUI or command-line tool; but it does have to work on old(ish) Linux distributions.

Encryption/security are not a consideration for me.

I don't mind if this were implemented as a Firefox extension - although I couldn't find one.

The tool has to be gratis, but doesn't have to be free software.